# i want to perform a redirect from a service in my angular 2 app

Tags: angular, auth0

I am learning angular 2 and i am trying to create a scenario where my user is presented with a home page and logs into my application using Auth0 after which i want the user to be redirected to a dashboard page from within the authentication service.

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { myConfig }        from './auth.config';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {});

  constructor(private router:Router) {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) =>
    {
        this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken,function (error: any, profile: any)
        {
          if(error)
          {
            throw new Error;
          }
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
          localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        });


    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  };

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // It searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired();
  };

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('profile');

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  };
}
```

I am using the Auth0 provided template for the authentication service, then i added the router.navigate function in the login function but my user is still presented with the login page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `function` inside a TypeScript class... This will mess up the `this` context. Only use arrow function notation `() => {}`. This will maintain the `this` context to that of the class:

```
this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error: any, profile: any) => { //here
      if(error)
      {
        throw new Error;
      }
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
      localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
});
```

Comment: That worked, but now it shows me only the router-outlet portion of my dashboard without displaying the other elements i have on the page like the sidebar.